# Merge unsorted lines from two files based on similar part

Tags: bash, merge

I am wondering if is it possible to merge information from two files together based on a similar part. file1 is ID with sequence after the blast, and file2 contains taxonomic names corresponding to two first numbers in name of sequences.

file 1:

```
>301-89_IDNAGNDJ_171582
>301-88_ALPEKDJF_119660
>301-88_ALPEKDJF_112039
...
```

file2:

```
301-89--sample1
301-88--sample2
...
```

output:

```
>301-89_IDNAGNDJ_171582--sample1
>301-88_ALPEKDJF_119660--sample2
>301-88_ALPEKDJF_112039--sample2
```

The files are unsorted and file1 contains more lines where is first two numbers similar to the first two numbers in one line in file2. I am looking for some tips/help on how to do that, it is possible to do that like this? which command or language should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(mawk/nawk/gawk -e/-ce/-Pe) '

   FNR == !_ {
      _ = !  ( ___=match(FS=FNR==NR ? "[-][-]" : "[>_]", "[>-]"))
     $_ = $_ 
 } FNR == NR { __[$!_]="--"$NF; next } sub("$", __[$___])' file2.txt file1.txt
```

———————————————————————————

```
        >301-89_IDNAGNDJ_171582--sample1
        >301-88_ALPEKDJF_112039--sample2
        >301-88_ALPEKDJF_119660--sample2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`

```
$ awk -F"[_-]" 'BEGIN{OFS="-"}NR==FNR{a[$2]=$4;next}{print $0,a[$2]}' file2 OFS="--" file1
>301-89_IDNAGNDJ_171582--sample1
>301-88_ALPEKDJF_119660--sample2
>301-88_ALPEKDJF_112039--sample2
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering if is it possible to merge information from two files together based on a similar part

Yes ...

> The files are unsorted

... but only if they're sorted.

It's easier if we transform them so the delimiters are consistent, and then format it back together later:

1. `sed 's/>\([0-9]*-[0-9]*\)_\(.*\)$/\1 \2/' file1` produces

   ```
   301-88 ALPEKDJF_112039
   301-88 ALPEKDJF_119660
   301-89 IDNAGNDJ_171582
   ...
   ```

   which we can just pipe through `sort -k1`
2. `sed 's/--/ /' f2` produces

   ```
   301-89 sample1
   301-88 sample2
   ...
   ```

   which we can sort the same way
3. `join sorted1 sorted2` (with the sorted results of the previous steps) produces

   ```
   301-88 ALPEKDJF_112039 sample2
   301-88 ALPEKDJF_119660 sample2
   301-89 IDNAGNDJ_171582 sample1
   ...
   ```
4. and finally we can format those 3 fields as you originally wanted, by piping through

   `sed 's/\(.*\) \(.*\) \(.*\)$/\1_\2--\3/'`

If it's reasonable to sort them on the fly, we can just do that using process substitution:

```
$ join \
     <( sed 's/>\([0-9]*-[0-9]*\)_\(.*\)$/\1 \2/' f1 | sort -k1 ) \
     <( sed 's/--/ /' f2 | sort -k1 ) \
      | sed 's/\(.*\) \(.*\) \(.*\)$/\1_\2--\3/'

301-88_ALPEKDJF_112039--sample2
301-88_ALPEKDJF_119660--sample2
301-89_IDNAGNDJ_171582--sample1
...
```

---

If it's not reasonable to sort the files - on the fly or otherwise - you're going to end up building a hash in memory, like the `awk` answer is doing. Give them both a try and see which is faster.

Comment: The final sed call could be simplied as  ::: sed -E 's/ /\_/; s/ /--/' :::  or ::: sed -E 's/ .+ /\_&--/g; s/ //g' :::: no back-references(BR) needed. if you prefer BR, then it's :::::  sed -E 's/ (.+) /\_\1--/'   ::::  If you prefer an awk-based solution for last step, then it's ::::: mawk 'NF-=sub(" ","_")' OFS='--' ::::::

Comment: Yeah, I wrote everything out very explicitly because I wasn't sure how stable and precisely-defined the format is, but it definitely ended up being overkill.

Comment: i mostly meant by activating -E flag for ERE, it looks cleaner with :::::::::: (.+) ::::::::::::::::::: instead of ::::::::::::::::::: \\(.\+\\)